# Nav menu does not center in wrapper div, margin: 0 auto; does not work

Tags: html, css, menu

I'm trying to get my navigation menu to be in the center of the page.

I've modified the code sample from a tute:

http://jsfiddle.net/B5qkF/

That is, what I'm after is for the blue menu to appear in the middle of the wrapper (**Note:** the wrapper is width 100%)

```
<div id="menu-wrapper">
    <ul id="menu">
        <li>...</li>
        <li>...
            <ul>
                <li>...</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>...</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I've tried adding `margin: 0px auto;` to `#menu-wrapper` and `#menu` but neither worked. Although manually setting `margin: 0px 100px;` does the trick.

Additionally, there is an overflow when I hover over the **sub-menu** buttons (the orange ones) - the light orange highlight overflows on the right side. Is there a way to remove it?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/B5qkF/7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i hope you are looking like this :- [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/B5qkF/8/)

**CSS**

```
#menu {

    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 800px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `margin: 0px auto;` to `#menu-wrapper` instead try below to center the `#menu`

```
#menu-wrapper{
text-align: center;
}
```